# How to get a function from a list element?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I have a set of arguments in a list like:

```
uy = {21/2 + y/2, 13.6667 + 0.666667 y, 20 + y}
```

Now, I want to assign a function (call it 'f(y)') to an element of that list:

```
f[y_] := uy[[1]][y]
```

It seems the way I define f(y) it's not correct. Any suggestions on how to define it properly?

Thank you very much

An in order to obtain a list of functions f? I mean:

```
For[i = 1, 4 > i,

 f[[i]][y_] = uy[[i]]; 

 i++]
```

Comment: This is at least one case where one would want to use `=` instead of `:=`: `Clear[y]; f[y_] = uy[[1]]`. I am certain this is a dupe of a previous question, but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a list of pure functions:

```
flist = Function[y, #] & /@ uy;
```

And then

```
f = flist[[1]]
```

Or directly:

```
f = Function@@{y, uy[[1]]}
```